# SharePoint Get Items is not returning all the columns

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I've got a flow that fetches items from a SharePoint list, however a lot of the columns are not coming back in the data that is fetched.

They do show up in the flow UI as options in subsequent actions but are always blank.
Running a test run the details show the JSON returned data doesn't the columns I want.
The columns are all types: single line text, choice, Yes/No, currency, there doesn't seem to be a pattern.

Here is a diagram of the flow if it helps:
[image]

Has anyone encountered this before and found a solution?
I've tried setting "Limit Columns by View" to Get all the columns and to a specific view but no luck.

Comment: Can you post your flow diagram to reproduce it?

Comment: How much items is inside to your sharepoint list ?? Maybe is a limit threshold problem.

Comment: @TấnNguyên added a picture if that helps.

Comment: @G.Mich There are only 264 items in the list currently.
I'll try fetching it directly via REST to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I am still having troubles with "Limit Columns by View" - in my case, it is returning ALL columns, rather than just those that are shown in the View specified.